# Apollo Cache - Missing selection set for object of type undefined returned for query field names

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am building an app with apollo-boost, which should include already some of the packages to do a react app with graphql.

I am facing an error at the moment I want to store pieces of data into my Apollo cache.

ApolloClient.tsx

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'

import { secretToken } from './secretToken'

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://someUrlIremovedForTheQuestion.com',
  request: async operation => {
    operation.setContext({
      headers: {
        Authorization: secretToken
      }
    })
  },
  cache
})

client.writeData({
  data: {
    names: [
      {
        firstName: 'Mario'
      },
      {
        firstName: 'Luigi'
      }
    ]
  }
})
export default client
```

Now I am trying to access to these names I created here in the same apollo config:

MyComponent.tsx

```
const result = client.readQuery({ query: gql`
      query namesCached {
        names @client
      }`
    })
console.log(result)
```

this is always falling into this error:

`Missing selection set for object of type undefined returned for query field names`

If I am doing a single piece of data, like `name: 'Mario'`, that works perfect and retrieve that piece of data, but for deeper objects or arrays it always fails with this error.

I am using Typescript as well

Any idea what could be? Stack overflow is shown me a couple non-working answers and GitHub is not providing me the solution either...

**Edit**
So here it comes my real example to make it more close to my real issue:

```
<Query
    query={fetchdata}
    onCompleted={({ repository }) => client.writeData({
        data: {
          issues: repository.issues.edges
        }
      })
    }
  >
```

Basically I am doing a Query, and once is completed I want to store it in cache, since I am checking it multiple times to compare and filter some results.

I tried just with `repository` but still in the same error

To retrieve the data i am doing the same as above but with `issues` instead of `names`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs could do a better job of stressing this but objects you store in the cache should always have an appropriate `__typename`. Additionally, if you're going to store multiple objects of the same type in the cache, you should include an `id` property to ensure a unique cache key is generated for each item. In other words, your initial state should be:

```
names: [
  {
    __typename: 'Name',
    id: 0,
    firstName: 'Mario',
  },
  {
    __typename: 'Name',
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'Luigi'
  }
]
```

You then query the state like this:

```
query namesCached {
  names @client {
    firstName
  }
}
```

It's worth mentioning, though, that the above is not necessary unless you're storing objects. If you're working with scalars, like this:

```
names: [
  'Mario',
  'Luigi',
]
```

Then you don't need a selection set:

```
query namesCached {
  names @client
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, precisely I've been reading some answers you did in this kind of topic, so I am very glad you are taking your time to help me. This answer really explained a lot, thanks. Let me update my question, adding my real object from the app( since Mario and Luigi were kind of mock data)

Comment: When you query the `issues`, are you including a selection set (i.e. the child fields for that field)? If it's possible for you to share your repo, it would be easier to just see all the code.

Comment: Sir! All my respects :). My query has __typename for every subquery (since it comes from graphql itself) but was missing to specify which objects I wanted to retrieve there ( id, or firstName, or age, etc..). I've been checking in the docs where is this explained but didn't find it. Do you mind to send me the docs where they explain the importance of the __typename and why the cache would need a unique key, like id? Once again: Thank you :)